# How to remove Unwanted Icons on Launchpad Created by Chrome Canary?

Tags: ios, macos, osx-yosemite

I installed Google Chrome Canary on my OS X Yosemite, some icons called “YouTube”, “Google Search”, “Gmail” and “Google Drive” came to my Launchpad without my permission. how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling ,following lines of bash code works for me.

All icons that are from Chrome Canary are deleted :-)

```
sqlite3 $(sudo find /private/var/folders -name com.apple.dock.launchpad)/db/db "DELETE FROM apps WHERE title='Google  Drive';" && killall Dock

sqlite3 $(sudo find /private/var/folders -name com.apple.dock.launchpad)/db/db "DELETE FROM apps WHERE title='Gmail';" && killall Dock

sqlite3 $(sudo find /private/var/folders -name com.apple.dock.launchpad)/db/db "DELETE FROM apps WHERE title='Google Search';" && killall Dock

sqlite3 $(sudo find /private/var/folders -name com.apple.dock.launchpad)/db/db "DELETE FROM apps WHERE title='YouTube';" && killall Dock
```